# Vue3 property overloading?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am not sure, if I am using the right term in title, but here is what I try to achieve:

I would like to create a select component where you can pass either:

- an array of primitives
- or an array of objects. However, when you pass an array of objects, you should also be able to specify, which property of the object to use for a label, and, which property to use for the model value.

If I wanted to only use primitives, the code can work like this:

```
<script setup lang="ts" generic="T extends number | string">
const props = defineProps<{
  modelValue: T
  options: T[]
}>()

// etc.
```

If I wanted to only use objects, the starting code could be like this (but it still does not check, if `valueKey` is passed to understand, if its `modelValue` should be primitive:

```
<script setup lang="ts" generic="T extends object">
const props = defineProps<{
  modelValue: T | number | string
  options: T[]
  labelKey?: keyof T
  valueKey?: keyof T
}>()

// etc.
```

Can `script setup` actually handle what I want? Or maybe there is some other way I could use?